# Колебание отправляемых значений - WinSock2

Tags: c++, sfml, winsock

я делаю игру с использованием WinSock2 и sfml. Чтобы люди с большим пингом не задерживали её ход, я написал (взял с сайта) функцию, ждущую 3 милисекунды, после чего проверяющую, готов ли пользователь отправить данные. Если пользователь готов к отправке, то возвращается true, если не готов - false.

```cpp
bool readyToReceive(int sock, int interval = 3)
{
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(sock, &fds);

    timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = interval;

    return (select(sock+1, &fds, 0, 0, &tv) == 1);
}
```

В функцию получения я добавил эту проверку

```cpp
if (Clients[i].IsActive) {
                    char Clientbuffer[256];
                    if (readyToReceive(Clients[i].ClientSocket)) {
                        auto stat = recv(Clients[i].ClientSocket, Clientbuffer, sizeof(Clientbuffer), NULL); //Получаем байты
                        if (stat == SOCKET_ERROR)
                            break;
                        PackForSend PlayerPack = BytesToPack(Clientbuffer); //Байты в пакет
                        Clients[i].PosX = std::stoi(PlayerPack.getElement(0)[0]);
                        Clients[i].PosY = std::stoi(PlayerPack.getElement(1)[0]); // Достаём из пакета координаты игрока.
                        std::cout << "PosX = " << Clients[i].PosX << std::endl;
                    }
                    else
                        std::cout << "Poteren" << std::endl;

                }
```

Но вот беда - через некоторое время после включения клиента и хоста, координаты (даже если клиент не изменяет их) начинают колебаться - +-10 px, а сам ход игры начинает идти медленнее. При этом если мы проверку готовности заменим на true, то такой проблемы не будет.

Comment: Хотя тут не предоставлен [mcve], сразу бросается в глаза неправильное использование значения, возвращаемого `recv` - там содержится количество реально принятых байт.

Comment: `SOCKET_ERROR` ещё можно потерпеть. он принимает значение -1 как ошибка. что-то тут может быть другое. или параллельные потоки или порча памяти.  @user7860670

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что readyToReceive вызывается для каждого подключения по отдельности. И если подключения "чуточку тупят" (что в целом то нормально), то при десятке подключений может быть 30 секунд на цикл. По хорошему, нужно ждать все подключения в одном select

Comment: @KoVadim , я так и не смог найти реализацию нескольких сокетов в одном select. Все гайды найденные мной сводятся к тому, что надо добавить сокет, проверить его, отчистить select и идти дальше.

Comment: с помощью FD_SET можно выставлять много сокетов (в зависимости от оси там есть разница, но сотню-другую можно обычно всегда)

Comment: @KoVadim но по такой логике нам всё равно придётся проходить по каждому сокету, верно?

Comment: если Вы хотите получить хотя бы один сокет, доступный для записи - то это будет один select и потом пробежаться по сокетам и проверить, кто доступен. Если же нужно, что бы все сокеты были доступны для записи - тут сложнее

Comment: @KoVadim ,Я не знаю как работают другие мультиплеерные проекты, но я хочу сделать так: у нас есть время ожидания, оно делится на количество игроков, чтобы не замедляться когда, заходят новые. Каждую итерацию мы проверяем все сокеты последовательно, если клиент не отвечает, мы даём ему "предупреждение", если ответил и отправил пакет - предупреждения становятся нулём. Если предупреждений больше 10 - мы отключаем игрока.

Comment: Так как это tcp, то тут могут отвечать "долго", то есть несколько секунд. И если у Вас код - последовательный обход всех, то пока одного будете ждать, другие будут ждать сервер. Возможно, Вам подойдет udp вместо tcp - там многие хотелки значительно проще сделать